# JavaScript does not send data to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Firebug writes that request time of this script is 0 and add_comment_processor.php returns NULL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#send_button").click(function(){
                var request = {
                    'comment': $("#new_comment_textfield").val(), //Value of textfield
                    'anonymously': $(".anonymously").is(':checked') //Value of anonymous check-button
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'add_comment_processor.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        alert(json); //returns NULL, but firebug writes that reques time of this script is 0ms
                    },
                    data: request //name of my object
                });
            });
        });
```

**add_comment_processor.php**
It just returns data it received so it shouldn't cause any problem.

```
<?php
unset($authorized_user);
session_save_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\session');
session_start();

$authorized_id=$_SESSION['authorized_user']; //logged user

// Read from POST
$recieve_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

// decode JSON
$object = json_decode($recieve_data);

$comment=$object->comment;
$anonymously=$object->anonymously;

$send_array=array(
    'comment'=>$comment,
    'anonymously'=>$anonymously
);

echo json_encode($send_array);
exit();
```

Comment: Why did you delete your previous identical question which had a comment asking for more info and clarification?

Comment: this is first time I use this site and I couldn't edit my question properly. when I type in script alert(request.comment); it shows true value of textfield

Comment: What does Firebug show in the response body of the Ajax request?

Comment: When your request type already is `'json'`, you don't have to use `$.parseJSON(data);`. Actually, `$.parseJSON({});` returns `null`. What do you get when calling `console.log(data)` or `alert(data)`?

Comment: I am currently working on another computer with Chrome. Here are response headers: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2013 20:23:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.3.13
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 35
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: response body (echo) is {"comment":null,"anonymously":null}

Comment: Derija93, at the moment I just want to be sure values returned properly

Comment: Derija93, thanks, but script still sends nothing to php